# How to get Max value that has been mixed with character in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

i have a table defined like this:

```
Name       Value
-----      -----
Alice      MN21
Bob        MN22
```

i want to get the max value like

```
select Name,MAX(Value) as Value from #Character
```

and it will show

```
Name      Value
----      -----
Bob       MN22
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your value format remain same like only two character string and then number?

Comment: @SandipPatel Yep

Comment: What is your logic to compare two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplicity is best

```
select top 1 Name,Value from #Character order by Value desc
```

Comment: simplicity is best!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SUBSTRING** to get only numeric for same format as below:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
    Name, 
    Value,
    SUBSTRING(Value,3,LEN(Value)) AS MaxValue
FROM @tblTest order by CAST(SUBSTRING(Value,3,LEN(Value)) AS INT) DESC
```

Comment: Don't you get an error? If you take als Length the Length of Value and start at position 3, you get out of range.

Comment: I have already confirm that it follow same format, there is always first two character string and then numeric

Comment: I don't get error because as confirm with OP there is always first two character in string

Comment: That's right. Let's say you have the value MN22 like the example. Now you use your substring which starts at position 3 and the length 4, which should result by Len(Value). Now, what happens? Substring starts at the first 2 and goes four chars, but there are only 2 left. You see what i mean?

Comment: len(value) mean it fetch from position 3 to what ever length, it will not throw an error, i have tried example and then post an answer

Comment: Ah okay. Just know this from .NET and this would crash. Doesn't know that this works in t-sql. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #CH (NAME VARCHAR(20), VALUE VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #CH VALUES ('Alice', 'MN21'), ('Bob', 'MN22'), ('Angie', 'AO42'),('Karl', 'AO27');
SELECT NAME, MAXVAL, VALUE
FROM #CH
INNER JOIN (SELECT SUBSTRING(VALUE,1,2) AS LEFTPART, MAX(SUBSTRING(VALUE,3,2)) AS MAXVAL
            FROM #CH 
            GROUP BY SUBSTRING(VALUE,1,2)) B ON #CH.VALUE = B.LEFTPART+B.MAXVAL

Output:
NAME                 MAXVAL VALUE
-------------------- ------ ----------
Bob                  22     MN22
Angie                42     AO42
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Name,Value from #Character where value in (
   select MAX(CAST(value AS int)) from #Character)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Name,MAX(Value REGEXP '[0-9]{5}') as Value from #Character
```